# HIOS Plan Year 2016 XSD Schema

Tags: data-format, healthcare-finder-api

Can someone provide a link to the new (plan year 2016) XSD schema for HIOS admin/plan/rate/etc. data exchange? There have been changes to the XML format for this year and we need to update our ETL packages.

The latest available at SERFF is PY2014, as there were no changes for 2015.

https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/ is where it SHOULD be, but it's not there. (Also the site is broken at present...)

Also not at http://www.healthdata.gov/data/dataset/healthcare-finder-api

Thanks.

Comment: i don't see xsd but you mean the templates? http://www.serff.com/plan_management_data_templates_2015.htm

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, but that's not what I need. The templates generate XML files when they're saved, and to consume those in our automation we need the XSD files that describe the schema used in the XML. The ones for PY2014 are on the SERFF page, at the bottom of the page where the templates are for that year.

Answer (score 1):

These files are now posted on the SERFF site: [2016 QHP Templates](http://www.serff.com/plan_management_data_templates_2016.htm).